# Custom indexer on Magento2

Tags: magento2, indexer, mview

I'm trying to create a custom indexer on Magento2.

I defined a `mview.xml` and one `indexer.xml` as follows:

**indexer.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Indexer/etc/indexer.xsd">
    <indexer id="my_indexer" view_id="my_indexer" class="My\Indexer\Model\Indexer\Fulltext">
        <title translate="true">My Indexer</title>
        <description translate="true">My Indexer</description>
    </indexer>
</config>
```

**mview.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Mview/etc/mview.xsd">
    <view id="my_indexer" class="My\Module\Model\Indexer\Fulltext" group="indexer">
        <subscriptions>
            <table name="catalog_product_entity" entity_column="entity_id" />
            <table name="catalog_product_entity_int" entity_column="entity_id" />
            <table name="catalog_product_entity_decimal" entity_column="entity_id" />
            <table name="catalog_product_entity_text" entity_column="entity_id" />
            <table name="catalog_product_entity_varchar" entity_column="entity_id" />
            <table name="catalog_product_entity_datetime" entity_column="entity_id" />
            <table name="catalog_product_website" entity_column="product_id" />
            <table name="cataloginventory_stock_item" entity_column="product_id" />
            <table name="catalog_product_bundle_selection" entity_column="parent_product_id" />
            <table name="catalog_product_super_link" entity_column="product_id" />
            <table name="catalog_product_link" entity_column="product_id" />
        </subscriptions>
    </view>
</config>
```

I can see the new indexer in the Magento backend and I can run a reindex from the command line, but when I try to modify a product from backend it does not trigger the **mview** as I would expect.

It does not call the `execute` method in the Mview or Indexer class, but it works correctly if called from command line.

Any idea?

Comment: Hi, Have you got final solution over here ?

Comment: ned this solution too

Comment: Nope, no solution

Comment: Can you please add the code of Fulltext.php file?

Answer (score 0):

Answer: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8866

Generally, you should put your index in "**Update by Schedule**" state to make it works using **mview.xml** configurations.

Check this diagram: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/indexing.html

Answer (score -4):

You are missing a crontab.xml file. Specifics of each field can be found [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html#config-cli-cron-group-conf)

```
<config>
<group id="<group_name>">
    <job name="<job_name>" instance="<classpath>" method="<method>">
        <schedule><time></schedule>
    </job>
</group>
```

As an example see Customer moudule's [crontab.xml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0/app/code/Magento/Customer/etc/crontab.xml)

Comment: Why crontab is needed for mview? Shouldn't the execute method of mview class called for each modified row?