# Catalog Rule Product indexer process unknown error

Tags: magento2, reindex, catalog-rules

I am getting the following error : while running : bin/magento indexer:reindex

```
Catalog Rule Product indexer process unknown error: 
Table status for `catalogrule_rule_cl` is incorrect. Can`t fetch version id.
```

Also tried [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/164315/magento-2-tables-being-created-ending-in-cl?rq=1) but didn't work out. Can someone explain ?

Comment: I'm having the same problem and it comes from Magento\Framework\Mview\View\Changelog where it does a SHOW TABLE query. 'Auto_Increment' is coming back null. Don't know why because it's not null. I tried recreating the table and still returns null.