# "indexer_update_all_views" cron job runs seemingly forever

Tags: magento2, cron, indexing

We are currently having the problem that the `indexer_update_all_views` cron job seemingly runs forever - even though there aren't that many entries in the backlog of the indexer.

Last time we let the cron process run for almost 24 hours before killing it manually. For comparison: doing a complete manual `indexer:reset` and `indexer:reindex` only takes about 60 to 90 minutes.

Could it be that the `indexer_update_all_views` somehow gets stuck or deadlocked? There aren't any errors in the logs - and the process simply "never" finishes (which it would if there was an error).

Any ideas?

Magento version: `2.3.2`

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/36724
This helped me. Theres a quality patch for this now.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to - at least temporarily - fix the problem by doing a complete, manual reset of the indexing process.

First disable the cronjob. Make sure no job will be running anymore (`ps aux | grep bin/magento`).

Then execute the following SQL statements:

```
// reset the cron_schedule table, in case you killed processes manually
TRUNCATE TABLE `cron_schedule`;

// reset all the indexing trigger tables
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_flat_cl`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product_cl`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_attribute_cl`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_category_cl`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_flat_cl`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_price_cl`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_cl`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalogrule_product_cl`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalogrule_rule_cl`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalogsearch_fulltext_cl`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_dummy_cl`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `design_config_dummy_cl`;

// reset the mview and indexer state tables
UPDATE `mview_state` SET `version_id` = '0', `status` = 'idle';
UPDATE `indexer_state` SET `status` = 'invalid';
```

Then do a complete re-index:

```
bin/magento indexer:reset && bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

After the re-indexing is finished, enable the cron again.

See also https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/164321/37461

Comment: all indexing cron is working fine but product quantity and price are not updating.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, would really be helpful to find an answer.

I have been monitoring this for weeks now. It seems to work when there is no other process in the backlog, but as soon as there are items in the backlog, this process gets stuck, and can run for 8-16 hours.

Magento version 2.3.1 (soon 2.3.2 when we find the time).

As far as I can tell the process "indexer_update_all_views" is related to EAV. EAV manually run takes about 8 minutes on a database with 660000 products - 40000 configs, the rest simple.