# Downloadable product on Magento 2.3.1 out of stock issue

Tags: magento2, stock, out-of-stock, downloadable, stock-status

I'm issuing a problem with **newly created downloadable products** on Magento 2.3.1

This store contains about 10k products (phisical and digital) imported from M1

- Phisical in stock/out of stock is working both for imported and native products
- Digital in stock/out of stock is working **only for M1 imported products**.

I compared the records of 2 digital products (1 imported and 1 native) in all %stock% database tables and the only strange things I noticed is that:

- M2 **native** downloadable product has **several records** on cataloginventory_stock_cl table
- M2 **imported** downloadable product has **no records** on cataloginventory_stock_cl table

What is the use of *cataloginventory_stock_cl* table?

There are other places where I can find to debug this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In our case the issue was related to a migration from Magento 1 to Magento 2 via migration data tool. The problem is that default value for the attribute 'links_exist' is `0` in Magento 1. However in Magento 2 default value for 'links_exist' is `null`.
Because of that following validation fails

```
File: vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml
Line 13: <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
```

which leads to

```
File: vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product.php
Line 1805: return $this->isSalable();
Line 1748: $salable = $this->isAvailable();
Line 1766: return $this->_catalogProduct->getSkipSaleableCheck() || $this->getTypeInstance()->isSalable($this);
```

Last part is important: `$this->getTypeInstance()->isSalable($this);`. In case of a downloadable product following validation happens:

```
File: vendor/magento/module-downloadable/Model/Product/Type.php
Line 334: return $this->hasLinks($product) && parent::isSalable($product);
```

This validation will return `false` for new created downloadables because of mentioned default value `0` for `links_exist`.

`File: vendor/magento/module-downloadable/Model/Product/Type.php`

```
Line 169-176:

public function hasLinks($product)
{
    $hasLinks = $product->getData('links_exist');
    if (null === $hasLinks) {
        $hasLinks = (count($this->getLinks($product)) > 0);
    }
    return $hasLinks;
}
```

Here your can see that Magento 2 expects `null` before even considering counting links.

That all said the issue is only related to newly created downloadables. Imported ones will most likely have a different value for `links_exist` which will pass mentioned validation.

Our solution was to manually change the default value for links exist in `eav_attributes` table. This should solve the issue for new downloadables.

Hope I could help.

**Edit:**
This bug is already reported on GitHub see: [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/issues/710).

**Edit 2:**

For downloadables that were created with a wrong default value for `links_exist` it is necessary to change the attribute value in `catalog_product_entity_int`.
Following query will help (substitute `attribute_id` and `entity_id` appropriately):

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_int SET value=null WHERE attribute_id="attribute id of links_exist" AND entity_id="insert product id here";
```

You can find `attribute_id` of `links_exist` in `eav_attribute` table.

Comment: I tried your workaround but it don't worked. https://www.screencast.com/t/j2qlgBZCXM0 Not sure if the others "null" values are correct

Comment: I also checked **catalog_product_entity_int** table: M1 downloadable products has  links_exist = 1, M2 downloadable products has links_exist = 0. If I update this value to 1, the product became "salable".

Comment: I forgot to mention that you have to change values in catalog_product_entity_int for already created downloadables as well. Sorry for that. I will update my answer in a minute.

Comment: after applying workaround, newly created produts has links_exist = 0

Comment: Try cleaning/flushing cache and reindex.

Answer (score 1):

`cl` ending on the table means "chanage log".

Run:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

And you should be able to see changes in those tables. The above command should hopefully fix the problem with the OOS products.

Have a look at this: [Magento 2 Tables Being Created Ending in "_cl"](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/164315/magento-2-tables-being-created-ending-in-cl)

Comment: I manually reindexed several times trying also do prior invalidate this indexes with no success. :-(

Comment: What do you see when you do reindex:status?

Comment: All indexes are *ready*