# How can i get rid of m2_cl tables which are created in my Database

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9

We have outsourced a `Magento` developer to migrate `M1` website to `M2`, this process is going on since few months now, suddenly since few day my Website is loading super slow, I checked all aspects but nothing actually worked. The Ram usage is suddenly increased by a lot, I tried deleting that new website + its database but still no fix. I tried deleting all the `m2_cl` tables which are newly created because of the data migration tool, then my website worked smooth for some time and crashed, after restoring it back it was working fine for some time and then again back to the issue. If anyone know how can I remove `M2_cl` tables safely. This might fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware! _cl tables are NOT related to M1 to M2 migration, but to M2 reindex process.

See here an useful answer: [Magento 2 Tables Being Created Ending in "_cl"](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/164315/magento-2-tables-being-created-ending-in-cl)

Comment: The tables referred to in the question have names that start with 'm2_cl', and are created as part of the Magento 1 to Magento 2 migration. Tables with names that end with '_cl' are not related to migration.

Answer (score 0):

> **php bin/magento migrate:delta -a path to config.xml**

once your incremental chnages done then run reindex command it will remove automatically

Comment: Can you pls explain me in detail, the steps and our free lancer developer who was working on this project has left us & I need to figure  a way out to remove those tables.

Comment: you have run this command on server where your data migration tool  is

Comment: I am restoring the new website folder which I deleted to check the website performance. Once its restored I need to check the data migration tool.