# Magento 2 var/lib/mysql/release is taking up 52 G of memory

Tags: magento2

Due to some reason my Magento 2 ver. 2.3.3 website is taking too much space from the server . Is there anything I can do about this or something I just have to deal with?

I was looking at this but it didn't really help me.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61955774/magento-2-2-6-var-lib-mysql-folder-is-taking-43-gb-of-disk-space

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The large tables ending in `_cl` are *changelog* tables created by the index MView process.

The _cl tables should automatically be deleted by a system cron job, it looks like yours are not being deleted and are becoming very large.

It should be ok to truncate these tables, but you need to find out why they are not being managed by the system - are your cron jobs running correctly?

This answer provides additional information about this problem and how to truncate the tables [Magento 2 Tables Being Created Ending in "_cl"](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/164315/magento-2-tables-being-created-ending-in-cl)

Here is the official documentation for the MView index process: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/multi-master/multi-master.html

**Be sure to take a db backup before making any changes!**