# Magento 2 cronjob doesn't seen to work

Tags: magento2, server-setup, cronjobs

I'm using Magento 2 v 2.3.3 with Ubuntu. I have cron job activated but for some reason doesn't it seem to work and my website is taking up alot of server memory. On my var/lib/mysql it's taking up around 62G.

As far as I can see everything seem to be runing as it should. It doesn't even print out any log files. And It seem to have the correct folder permission. Any ide of what the problem can be? Thanks!

I have already checked:

- [Magento 2 Tables Being Created Ending in "_cl"](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/164315/magento-2-tables-being-created-ending-in-cl)
- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/multi-master/multi-master.html
- https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/sales-channels/google-eol.html

```
#~ MAGENTO START d9133c30253161587b8cc6041f13f89ad82e43ff1211994ea3d5d2c68babc079
0 9 * * 2 /usr/bin/php7.3 /var/www/html/root/bin/magento cron:run 2>&1 | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /var/www/html/root/var/log/magento.cron.log
0 10 * * 3 /usr/bin/php7.3 /var/www/html/root/update/cron.php >> /var/www/html/root/var/log/update.cron.log
0 11 * * 3 /usr/bin/php7.3 /var/www/html/root/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /var/www/html/root/var/log/setup.cron.log
#~ MAGENTO END d9133c30253161587b8cc6041f13f89ad82e43ff1211994ea3d5d2c68babc079
```

```
-----------------------------------------------------+----------------+------+------+---+---+----+
| Job                                                 | Group          | m    | h    | D | M | WD |
+-----------------------------------------------------+----------------+------+------+---+---+----+
| aggregate_sales_report_bestsellers_data             | default        | 0    | 0    | * | * | *  |
| aggregate_sales_report_coupons_data                 | default        | 0    | 0    | * | * | *  |
| aggregate_sales_report_invoiced_data                | default        | 0    | 0    | * | * | *  |
| aggregate_sales_report_order_data                   | default        | 0    | 0    | * | * | *  |
| aggregate_sales_report_refunded_data                | default        | 0    | 0    | * | * | *  |
| aggregate_sales_report_shipment_data                | default        | 0    | 0    | * | * | *  |
| aggregate_sales_report_tax_data                     | default        | 0    | 0    | * | * | *  |
| analytics_collect_data                              | default        | 00   | 02   | * | * | *  |
| analytics_subscribe                                 | default        | -    | -    | - | - | -  |
| analytics_update                                    | default        | -    | -    | - | - | -  |
| aw_rp_expiration_check                              | default        | *    | *    | * | * | *  |
| aw_rp_expiration_reminder                           | default        | 0    | */1  | * | * | *  |
| backend_clean_cache                                 | default        | 30   | 2    | * | * | *  |
| bulk_cleanup                                        | default        | *    | *    | * | * | *  |
| captcha_delete_expired_images                       | default        | */10 | *    | * | * | *  |
| captcha_delete_old_attempts                         | default        | */30 | *    | * | * | *  |
| catalog_index_refresh_price                         | default        | 0    | *    | * | * | *  |
| catalog_product_alert                               | default        | 0    | 0    | * | * | *  |
| catalog_product_attribute_value_synchronize         | default        | */5  | *    | * | * | *  |
| catalog_product_flat_indexer_store_cleanup          | default        | 0    | 0    | * | * | *  |
| catalog_product_frontend_actions_flush              | default        | *    | *    | * | * | *  |
| catalog_product_outdated_price_values_cleanup       | default        | *    | *    | * | * | *  |
| catalogrule_apply_all                               | default        | 0    | 1    | * | * | *  |
| consumers_runner                                    | consumers      | *    | *    | * | * | *  |
| currency_rates_update                               | default        | -    | -    | - | - | -  |
| ddg_automation_abandonedcarts                       | ddg_automation | */5  | *    | * | * | *  |
| ddg_automation_campaign                             | ddg_automation | */5  | *    | * | * | *  |
| ddg_automation_catalog_sync                         | ddg_automation | -    | -    | - | - | -  |
| ddg_automation_cleaner                              | ddg_automation | 0    | 0    | 1 | * | *  |
| ddg_automation_customer_subscriber_guest_sync       | ddg_automation | -    | -    | - | - | -  |
| ddg_automation_email_templates                      | ddg_automation | 0    | */6  | * | * | *  |
| ddg_automation_importer                             | ddg_automation | -    | -    | - | - | -  |
| ddg_automation_order_sync                           | ddg_automation | -    | -    | - | - | -  |
| ddg_automation_reviews_and_wishlist                 | ddg_automation | -    | -    | - | - | -  |
| ddg_automation_status                               | ddg_automation | */15 | *    | * | * | *  |
| expired_tokens_cleanup                              | default        | 0    | *    | * | * | *  |
| iceshop_iceimport_job                               | default        | -    | -    | - | - | -  |
| indexer_clean_all_changelogs                        | index          | 0    | *    | * | * | *  |
| indexer_reindex_all_invalid                         | index          | *    | *    | * | * | *  |
| indexer_update_all_views                            | index          | *    | *    | * | * | *  |
| magento_newrelicreporting_cron                      | default        | */2  | *    | * | * | *  |
| mageplaza_smtp_clear_log                            | default        | 0    | 0    | * | * | *  |
| messagequeue_clean_outdated_locks                   | default        | 0    | *    | * | * | *  |
| mp_cron_search                                      | default        | 0    | 0    | * | * | *  |
| mysqlmq_clean_messages                              | default        | 30   | 6,15 | * | * | *  |
| newsletter_send_all                                 | default        | */5  | *    | * | * | *  |
| outdated_authentication_failures_cleanup            | default        | *    | *    | * | * | *  |
| persistent_clear_expired                            | default        | 0    | 0    | * | * | *  |
| sales_clean_orders                                  | default        | 0    | *    | * | * | *  |
| sales_clean_quotes                                  | default        | 0    | 0    | * | * | *  |
| sales_grid_order_async_insert                       | default        | *    | *    | * | * | *  |
| sales_grid_order_creditmemo_async_insert            | default        | *    | *    | * | * | *  |
| sales_grid_order_invoice_async_insert               | default        | *    | *    | * | * | *  |
| sales_grid_order_shipment_async_insert              | default        | *    | *    | * | * | *  |
| sales_send_order_creditmemo_emails                  | default        | *    | *    | * | * | *  |
| sales_send_order_emails                             | default        | *    | *    | * | * | *  |
| sales_send_order_invoice_emails                     | default        | *    | *    | * | * | *  |
| sales_send_order_shipment_emails                    | default        | *    | *    | * | * | *  |
| scconnector_retrieve_gtag                           | scconnector    | */10 | *    | * | * | *  |
| scconnector_verify_website                          | scconnector    | */10 | *    | * | * | *  |
| security_clean_admin_expired_sessions               | default        | 0    | 0    | * | * | *  |
| security_clean_password_reset_request_event_records | default        | 0    | 0    | * | * | *  |
| sitemap_generate                                    | default        | 0    | 0    | * | * | *  |
| system_backup                                       | default        | 0    | 0    | * | * | *  |
| temando_process_platform_events                     | default        | */15 | *    | * | * | *  |
| visitor_clean                                       | default        | 0    | 0    | * | * | *  |
| yotpo_yotpo_orders_sync                             | yotpo_yotpo    | *    | *    | * | * | *  |
| yotpo_yotpo_update_metadata                         | yotpo_yotpo    | 30   | 2    | * | * | *  |
+-----------------------------------------------------+----------------+------+------+---+---+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

are you sure your php executable is called "*php7.3*" as shown in your cron command line.

Enter `whereis php` on the command line to find the path and name of the executable, it usually is **php**

Also your cron should run every minute

```
* * * * * /path/to/bin/php /path/to/magento2/bin/magento cron:run 2>&1 | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/magento.cron.log
```

Yours are running at very erratic times and only once a week...

```
0 9 * * 2 - At 09:00 on Tuesday
0 10 * * 3 - At 10:00 on Wednesday
0 11 * * 3 - At 11:00 on Wednesday
```

You should change the cron run time for all three jobs to once every minute

```
* * * * * /cron/job/...
```